# How to add NTFS partition on remote server to VMWare ESXi 5.1

Tags: windows, virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-converter

I have ESXi 5.1 running on a standalone box. On another server, I have Windows 2008 R2 installed and it has a 1 TB partition free. Both are on the same network. I am a complete noob to VMWare and I'd like to know the easiest way to use that 1 TB partition as a datastore/available resource on my ESXi server.

Will I have to convert the entire Windows 2008 R2 server using VMWare converter? If so, what will that do to my Windows server? Will it still run normally with Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stop thinking about converting the Windows server as that's irrelevant to what you're trying to do.

You can use the local storage of the Windows server as a datastore for your vSphere server, although doing that isn't exactly the way I would go about adding storage to a vSphere server. That being said, here's what you can do:

Download and install the iSCSI Target software for the Windows server. Once installed you can create and configure the software to present iSCSI targets to your vSphere server.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19867

Comment: was a breeze to set up! now have an additional TB from my Windows server to play with! Thank you!!

Comment: Glad to help...